# Who's the composer of "Wanted"?

Tags: instrumental

I can't find information anywhere about this tune. Shazam does not know either

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RE9m8Rzm_mc

Answer (score 3):

**[Doogy Degli Armonium](http://melodiesmagic.blogspot.com.br/2014/12/doogy-degli-armonium-mescaleros-wanted.html?m=1) - Wanted 1976**

> Made By – EMI Italiana S.p.A.
>
> Published By – La Voce Del Padrone
>
> Phonographic Copyright (p) – EMI Italiana S.p.A.
>
> **Written By –
>   Franco Zulian**